# obtaining Bernoulli numbers from determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

I am reading a paper entitled Bernoulli Numbers Via Determinants by Hongwei Chen and I'm confused about a particular step.  The author sets up a system of equations via the following: first let $B_n$ represent the $n$-th Bernoulli number.  Then

$$x=(e^x-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Letting $b_n=B_n/n!$ and expanding we get

$$x=\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...\right)\left(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...\right)$$

Immediately we can see that $b_0=1$.  Using Cauchy Products, we then obtain an infinite sequence of equations which are coefficients of the powers of $x$. But we don't need infinite, we can look at the system for coefficients up to $x^n$.   Therefore

\begin{cases}
b_1=-\frac{1}{2!} \\[2ex]
\frac{b_1}{2!}+b_2=-\frac{1}{3!} \\[2ex]
\frac{b_1}{3!}+\frac{b_2}{2!}+b_3=-\frac{1}{4!} \\[2ex]
\vdots \\[2ex]
\frac{b_1}{n!}+\frac{b_2}{(n-1)!}+...+b_n=-\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \\[2ex]
\end{cases}

Then the author goes on to state that applying Cramers rule produces
$$b_n=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -\frac{1}{2!} \\
\frac{1}{2!} & 1 & 0 & \cdots & -\frac{1}{3!} \\
\frac{1}{3!} & \frac{1}{2!} & 1 & \cdots & -\frac{1}{4!} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{n!} & \frac{1}{(n-1)!} & \frac{1}{(n-2)!} & \cdots & -\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Then

$$B_n=n!
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -\frac{1}{2!} \\
\frac{1}{2!} & 1 & 0 & \cdots & -\frac{1}{3!} \\
\frac{1}{3!} & \frac{1}{2!} & 1 & \cdots & -\frac{1}{4!} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{n!} & \frac{1}{(n-1)!} & \frac{1}{(n-2)!} & \cdots & -\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

And finally,

$$B_n=(-1)^n n!
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{1}{2!} & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3!} & \frac{1}{2!} & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\frac{1}{4!} & \frac{1}{3!} & \frac{1}{2!} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{(n+1)!} &\frac{1}{n!} & \frac{1}{(n-1)!} &  \cdots & \frac{1}{2!} \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Can someone please explain the last step?  I just don't see how that last step comes from the previous.  I figure it has something to do with properties of determinants, and i do know that $|cA|=c^n|A|$, but I don't see where that is coming from here.

Comment: The last step comes from interchanging columns and $c=-1$.

Comment: And so, if you do that, you only do that $n-1$ times...then the sign of the left most column is still negative...can you also take out a $-1$ then since the column is a scalar multiple? It's been a while since I've done determinants...

Comment: @DietrichBurde, is my last statement correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

If $c$ is a constant and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then
$\det c A = c^n \det A$. Note that here $c$ multiplies all columns
not just the first column. Now, if $c$ multiplies only one column
then $\det [A_1, A_2, \cdots, c A_i, \cdots A_n]= c \det A$.

Now for the problem. The constant $c=-1$ only multiplies the first
column after being rolled from the last place ($n-1$ swaps).

Then we have the total sign is $(-1)^{n-1} (-1) = (-1)^n$.

Comment: In *Mathematica*, I typed in `B[n_] := (-1)^n n! Det[
   Table[If[r + 1 < c, 0, 1/(r - c + 2)!], {r, 1, n}, {c, 1, n}]]` followed by `BernoulliB[#] - B[#] & /@ Range[10]`.  The result was all zeros.

Comment: I see. So where is the error in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: What Wolfram Alpha (and *Mathematica*) will do when you specify a **matrix** multiplied by a constant, is to multiply **every** element in the matrix by that constant.  What you need to type is (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4!+Det[{{1%2F2,1,0,0},{1%2F3!,1%2F2,1,0},{1%2F4!,1%2F3!,1%2F2,1},{1%2F5!,1%2F4!,1%2F3!,1%2F2}}]) instead.

Comment: @heropup I believe you are correct. I did it in maxima and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to find a way to get access to the paper online, but I can't.  I get it through university website...

Comment: I guess my question is, when taking determinants, if a row has a multiple, you can take that out...can you also do that for columns?

Comment: It is fine. I believe that the method used by Chen makes sense. I also believe is correct although I see your point. I found that the sign (see my answer) is "-1"  but I must be wrong. So your question at this moment is still valid and unanswered. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Yes, you could do that for rows or columns. The determinant of $A$ is equal to the determinant of $A^T$  (the transposed) so it does not matter. But there are two contributions to the sign. Swapping two columns changes the sign, and multiplying a column changes the sign by $(-1)^n$. Added together is $n+n-1 = 2n-1$ and for an odd number $ (-1)^{2n-1}=-1$